# SQLAlchemy: using array_agg to aggregate whole class/table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to execute a query in SQLAlchemy that returns an array of results. The SQL query looks as follows. 1 row from the table Boundingbox, and a spatial join on the table Tiletemplate. The joined Tiletemplate rows are aggregated into an array using aray_agg:

```sql
SELECT boundingbox, array_agg(tiletemplate) tiletemplate
FROM boundingbox JOIN tiletemplate ON ST_Intersects(tiletemplate.geom, boundingbox.geom) 
WHERE boundingbox.filepath = '<filepath>' GROUP BY boundingbox
```

When executing the query in DBeaver or pgAdmin it returns the expected results. A single row with the Boundingbox, and an array of intersecting Tiletemplates.
[DBeaver results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0yHQ.png)

In SQLAlchemy this does not seem to work.

```py
session.execute(select(Boundingbox, array_agg(Tiletemplate).label("tiletemplate")).where(
        Boundingbox.filepath == <filepath>).join(Tiletemplate, Tiletemplate.geom.ST_Intersects(Boundingbox.geom)).group_by(Boundingbox))
```

SQLAlchemy seems to not be able to aggregate complete models.

```
SQL expression element expected, got <class 'models.Tiletemplate.Tiletemplate'>.
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object <class 'models.Tiletemplate.Tiletemplate'> is not legal as a SQL literal value
```

Using `Tiletemplate.id` does work as expected, returning an array of all id's. However, I would like to have the complete intance of the model returned in the array, and not just 1 column.